# Foreach and getting tags and categories from other tables

Tags: database, laravel, foreach, tags

I had hard time to think about good title, but I hope that this explains.

**Posts table**

```
+----+---------+-----------------+
| id |  title  |      text       |
+----+---------+-----------------+
|  1 | Title 1 | This is example |
|  2 | Title 2 | This is example |
|  3 | Title 3 | This is example |
+----+---------+-----------------+
```

**Tags table**

```
+----+--------+
| id |  tag   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | jQuery |
|  2 | PHP    |
|  3 | Stack  |
+----+--------+
```

**Category table**

```
+----+------------+
| id |  category  |
+----+------------+
|  1 | Category 1 |
|  2 | Category 2 |
|  3 | Category 3 |
+----+------------+
```

**Post tags relation table (same thing with category)**

```
+---------+--------+
| post_id | tag_id |
+---------+--------+
|       1 |      1 |
|       1 |      2 |
|       2 |      3 |
+---------+--------+
```

This is the result what i want to see in my view:

```
+---------+------------------+--------------------+------------+
|  Title  |       Text       |        Tags        | Categories |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+------------+
| Title 1 | This is example  | jQuery, PHP        | Category 2 |
| Title 2 | This is example  | Stack              | Category 1 |
| Title 3 | This is example  | jQuery, PHP, Stack | Category 1 |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+------------+
```

In my controller i have

```
public function index()
{
  $posts = Posts::orderBy('title', 'ASC')->get();

  return View::make('posts', array(
    'posts' => $posts)
  );
}
```

And in my view I can list all posts with foreach loop

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
  Title: {{ $post->title }}
  Text: {{ $post->text }}
  Tags: ?
  Categories: ?
@endforeach
```

Question is that what is best way to get tags and categories for each post inside foreach loop?

Comment: Have you set up relations on the models, or you have no idea about the topic and need complete solution?

Comment: I read Laravel Eloquent ORM tutorial and made relations as suggested, but i'm not sure that if it was for my needs, cause in that situation the output was: Post title and text came to list as many times as there were different tags. In this situation i would need foreach loop for posts and inside that own foreach loops for tags and categories?

Comment: Sure, you get collection of posts with collections of related tags, and collection of related categories (if it's many to many too) / category model (if it's one to many). Read about eager loading too, as now you run query in every loop rep, so called n+1 problem

Comment: google "laravel pivot table", "Jeffrey Way's generator tool" look for pivot generator and its details, laravel's official documentation on relationship, and off-course the n+1 problem...

These types of relationships are easy to manage in laravel

Answer (score 0):

Shakil's tips was right on the spot and i found what i was looking for. I am surprised that it was so easy to achieve. Here is what i did:

**Posts -model**

```
class Posts extends Eloquent 
{
   protected $table = 'posts';

   public function tags()
   {
     return $this->belongsToMany('Tags', 'post_tags', 'post_id', 'tag_id');
   }

   public function category()
   {
     return $this->belongsToMany('Category', 'post_categories', 'post_id', 'category_id');
   }
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
  Title: {{ $post->title }}
  Text: {{ $post->text }}

  Tags: 
    @foreach ($post->tags as $tag)
      {{ $tag }}
    @endforeach

  Categories: 
    @foreach ($post->categories as $category)
     {{ $category }}
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Thanks for all for your help!